# Windows Azure DocumentRoot

Tags: windows, azure, subdirectory, htdocs

does somebody know how it is possible to change the document root for windows azure web application to a sub folder?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Not right now with the default web roles.

You can:

- [Implement your own web host](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/hwcworker) (hosting IIS core or any web server in web role)
- Wait a bit till Azure starts supporting more flexibility out-of-the box (I think this was announced at the last PDC).

Comment: Thx for the link, sounds very interessting, I'll try it. When it is easy to implement I'll give you the accecptance tick, too ;)